Trying to troubleshoot my PayPal ipn to have transactions verified and success notice
My details are inserted properly into MySQL database and PayPal message is received in my log. With the message is the following error information
FAIL: fsockopen error no. 0: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known.
<?php require_once('Connections/connstake.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('webassist/mysqli/queryobj.php'); ?>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
?><?php
require "paypal.class.php";
require "config.php"?>
<?php
$p = new paypal_class;
$p->paypal_url = $payPalURL;

if ($p->validate_ipn()) {
    if($p->ipn_data['payment_status']=='Completed')
    {
        $amount = $p->ipn_data['mc_gross'] - $p->ipn_data['mc_fee'];
    }
}
        ?>
        
<?php    // post back to Paypal system to validate
          header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
          ?>
<?php
if (true) {
  $InsertQuery = new WA_MySQLi_Query($connstake);
  $InsertQuery->Action = "insert";
  $InsertQuery->Table = "registration_paypal";
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("transaction_ID", "s", "".$_POST['txn_id']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("first_name", "s", "".$_POST['first_name']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("last_name", "s", "".$_POST['last_name']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("email1", "s", "".$_POST['payer_email']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("address_street", "s", "".$_POST['address_street']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("address_city", "s", "".$_POST['address_city']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("address_state", "s", "".$_POST['address_state']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("address_zip", "s", "".$_POST['address_zip']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("amount", "d", "".$amount  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("payment_gross", "s", "".$_POST['mc_gross']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("payment_fee", "s", "".$_POST['mc_fee']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("special_requests", "s", "".$_POST['memo']  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("original_request", "s", "".http_build_query($_POST)  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertQuery->saveInSession("");
  $InsertQuery->execute();
  $InsertGoTo = "";
  if (function_exists("rel2abs")) $InsertGoTo = $InsertGoTo?rel2abs($InsertGoTo,dirname(__FILE__)):"";
  $InsertQuery->redirect($InsertGoTo);
}
?>

Also using PayPal class from Micha Carrick and Sven Sauleau
<?php
/*******************************************************************************
 *                      PHP Paypal IPN Integration Class
 *******************************************************************************
 *      Author:     Sven Sauleau
 *      Email:      contact@xtuc.fr
 *      Website:    http://www.Xtuc.fr
 *
 *      Version:    2.0.0
 *      Copyright:  (c) 2014 - Sven Sauleau (Xtuc)
 *                  You are free to use, distribute, and modify this software 
 *                  under the terms of the GNU General Public License.  See the
 *                  included LICENCE file.
 *    
/*******************************************************************************
 *                      Initial Copyright
 ******************************************************************************* 
 *
 *      Author:     Micah Carrick
 *      Email:      email@micahcarrick.com
 *      Website:    http://www.micahcarrick.com
 *
 *      File:       paypal.class.php
 *      Version:    1.3.0
 *      Copyright:  (c) 2005 - Micah Carrick 
 *                  You are free to use, distribute, and modify this software 
 *                  under the terms of the GNU General Public License.  See the
 *                  included license.txt file.
 *    
 ******************************************************************************* 
*/

class paypal_class {
    
   var $last_error;                 // holds the last error encountered
   
   var $ipn_log;                    // bool: log IPN results to text file?
   
   var $ipn_log_file;               // filename of the IPN log
   var $ipn_response;               // holds the IPN response from paypal   
   var $ipn_data = array();         // array contains the POST values for IPN
   
   var $fields = array();           // array holds the fields to submit to paypal
   
   var $sandbox;

   
   function paypal_class($sandbox = FALSE) {
       
      // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.
      
    $this->sandbox = $sandbox;
    
        if($this->sandbox)
        {
            $this->paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }
      
      $this->last_error = '';
      
      $this->ipn_log_file = 'ipn_log.txt';
      $this->ipn_log = true; 
      $this->ipn_response = '';
      
      // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal
      // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul
      // values can be overwritten by the calling script.

      $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
      $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick'); 
      
   }
   
   function add_field($field, $value) {
      
      // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be 
      // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the 
      // array, it will be overwritten.
            
      $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
   }

   function submit_paypal_post() {
 
      // this function actually generates an entire HTML page consisting of
      // a form with hidden elements which is submitted to paypal via the 
      // BODY element's onLoad attribute.  We do this so that you can validate
      // any POST vars from you custom form before submitting to paypal.  So 
      // basically, you'll have your own form which is submitted to your script
      // to validate the data, which in turn calls this function to create
      // another hidden form and submit to paypal.
 
      // The user will briefly see a message on the screen that reads:
      // "Please wait, your order is being processed..." and then immediately
      // is redirected to paypal.

      echo "<html>\n";
      echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>\n";
      echo "<body onLoad=\"document.forms['paypal_form'].submit();\">\n";
      echo "<center><h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you";
      echo " will be redirected to the paypal website.</h2></center>\n";
      echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"paypal_form\" ";
      echo "action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";

      foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
         echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"/>\n";
      }
      echo "<center><br/><br/>If you are not automatically redirected to ";
      echo "paypal within 5 seconds...<br/><br/>\n";
      echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click Here\"></center>\n";
      
      echo "</form>\n";
      echo "</body></html>\n";
    
   }
   
   function validate_ipn() {

      // parse the paypal URL
      $url_parsed=parse_url($this->paypal_url);        

      // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
      // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
      // script.
      $post_string = '';    
      foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) { 
         $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
         $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&'; 
      }
      $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

      if($this->sandbox)
      {
        $fp = fsockopen("ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com",443,$err_num,$err_str,30);
      }
      else 
      {
        $fp = fsockopen("ssl://www.ipnpb.paypal.com",443,$errno,$errstr,30);
      }
      
      if(!$fp) {
        
         // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
         // will be in the log.
         $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errno: $errstr";
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);       
         return false;
         
      } else { 
 
         // Post the data back to paypal
         fputs($fp, "POST ". $url_parsed['path'] . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Host: ". $url_parsed['host'] . "\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); 
         //$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
         //$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
         //$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
         //$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
         //$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

         // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
         while(!feof($fp)) { 
            $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
         } 

         fclose($fp); // close connection

      }
      
      if (preg_match("/VERIFIED/", $this->ipn_response)) {
  
         // Valid IPN transaction.
         $this->log_ipn_results(true);
         return true;       
         
      } else {
  
         // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
         $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);   
         return false;
         
      }
      
   }
   
   function log_ipn_results($success) {
       
      if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off?
      
      // Timestamp
      $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '; 
      
      // Success or failure being logged?
      if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
      else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n";
      
      // Log the POST variables
      $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
      foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
         $text .= "$key=$value, ";
      }
 
      // Log the response from the paypal server
      $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;
      
      // Write to log
      $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
      fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n"); 

      fclose($fp);  // close file
   }

   function dump_fields() {
 
      // Used for debugging, this function will output all the field/value pairs
      // that are currently defined in the instance of the class using the
      // add_field() function.
      
      echo "<h3>paypal_class->dump_fields() Output:</h3>";
      echo "<table width=\"95%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
            <tr>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Field Name</font></b></td>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Value</font></b></td>
            </tr>"; 
      
      ksort($this->fields);
      foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
         echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".urldecode($value)."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
      }
 
      echo "</table><br>"; 
   }        
}




If I remember correctly, www.ipnpb.paypal.com is no longer used (seems replaced by ipnpb.paypal.com)

Ken Lee, thanks so much! I’ve been working on this for several weeks and that small change gave me a SUCCESS and VERIFIED result in my log. I appreciate it.
